# Compute adjusted McFadden's pseudo-R2 from deviances

Tags: r-squared

I know, that the "ordinary" McFadden's pseudo-R2 can be computed like this:

$$
R^2 = 1 - \frac{\text{Residual deviance}}{\text{Null deviance}},
$$

but today I've read about adjusted McFadden's pseudo-R2 [here](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/) and I thought if it's possible to compute it like this?

$$
R^2_{\text{adj}} = 1 - \frac{\text{Residual deviance}-K}{\text{Null deviance}}
$$

$K$ is the number of predictors.

Comment: It looks like your equation is correct but the paper said that $k$ was the number of predictors (to avoid over-fitting), not the number of observations.

Comment: @Tavrock Thank you, I meant predictors - it's corrected now. And could you, please, expand your comment to an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: @Tavrock And I notices, that with increasing $K$ the $R^2$ will increase to... Shouldn't I add $K$ to Residual deviance instead of substracting it?

Comment: This will be clear to anyone who carefully reads the accepted answer, but just to make it more obvious to casual readers: the equations in the question are not correct.

Comment: Yes, blokeman' Answer is essential. deviance = -2*LogL, so the numerator above should be Residual deviance + 2*K.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I too have only just now run into this adjusted R-squared. It seems a handy and useful diagnostic. I don't quite agree with your definition though. Rather than the number of predictors, K is the number of additional parameters relative to the null model. Unlike the number of predictors, the number of parameters includes interaction terms, random effects, dummy variables standing for non-reference categories of a nominal predictor, polynomials, etc.

Long (1997: 104) defines the statistic thus:

$$\begin{equation}
R^2_{adj} = 1 - \frac{logL(M) - K}{logL(M_{null})}
\end{equation}$$

where K, unless I'm mistaken, turns out to be the familiar Akaike penalty when converted to the Deviance scale.

---

Long, J. S. (1997). *Regression models for categorical and limited dependent variables*. Thousands Oaks: Sage.

Comment: If $K$ includes the intercept term, then why isn't the denominator $\ln L(M_{0})-1$ since the null model also includes an intercept?

Comment: Thanks. That should be fixed now.